# Why EventListener not fire in page context in Safari App Extension?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, custom-events, safari-app-extension

I'm trying to do something in the "page context", for this I inject the script in the page like this

```
var pageScript = document.createElement('script');
pageScript.textContent = actualCode;
document.body.insertBefore(pageScript, document.body.firstChild);
```

the `actualCoe` is

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    document.addEventListener(playerEventName, function(event) {
        console.log("page script fire"");
    });
} + ')();'; // end actualCode
```

but listener doesn't not fire when i sent message, in console i see only sent message name.

The full code of my script.js file

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    safari.extension.dispatchMessage("script injected successfully");
    init();
});

let playerEventName = "su.nagornyi.yam.ext.evnt";

var init = function() {

    console.log("init started");
          
    var pageScript = document.createElement('script');
    pageScript.textContent = actualCode;
    document.body.insertBefore(pageScript, document.body.firstChild);
}; // end init

var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    document.addEventListener(playerEventName, function(event) {
        console.log("page script fire");
    });
} + ')();'; // end actualCode

safari.self.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);

function handleMessage(event) {
    console.log(event.name);
    let playerEvent = new CustomEvent(playerEventName, {
        detail: {
            action: event.name
        }
    });
    document.dispatchEvent(playerEvent);
}; // end handleMessage
```

UPD: Error in console:

```
Refused to execute a script because its hash its nonce or 'unsafe-inline'does
not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Securrity policy.
```

So, is it possible to inject scrip on this page?

UPD2: **In Safari App Extension we can inject scripts only from file placed in extension bundle.**

Comment: The `playerEventName` variable is not in the same context as the code in the `<script>` that you are creating.

Comment: @Titus i change playerEventName on "string", but it did not help.

Comment: @Titus add your comment as answer and i mark it as a correct answer.